# Concatenate with string but exclude when null

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle v11

Exclude a string in a Concat when the value is NULL?

Work
Query:

```
Select 
 *
 LastName || ',' || FirstName AS Last_First_Name

 --I've tried using NVL & NVL2
 --NVL(LastName || ',' || FirstName,'') AS Last_First_Name2
 FROM TableA
```

TableA

```
LastName   FirstName  ID
 Smith       Ann      1
                      2
```

Output I'm getting

```
LastName FirstName ID   LastName_FirstName
 Smith       Ann    1    Smith,Ann
                    2    ,
```

Expected Output:

```
LastName FirstName ID   LastName_FirstName
 Smith       Ann    1    Smith,Ann
                    2
```

Comment: what if just one is `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this... I added simulated inputs to test all four possibilities. However, note that if you may have last name but no first name, and also first name but no last name, the combined column will show just one name but you will not know if it is first or last. (Also, when a comma is added, I also add a space after the comma, as is usual; that can be controlled easily though.)

```
with
  tablea ( lastname, firstname, id ) as (
               select 'Smith', 'Ann'  , 1 from dual
     union all select null   , null   , 2 from dual
     union all select 'Ang'  , null   , 3 from dual
     union all select null   , 'Murat', 4 from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select lastname, firstname, id,
       lastname 
         || case when lastname is not null and firstname is not null then ', ' end
         || firstname
       as last_first
from   tablea
;



LASTNAME   FIRSTNAME          ID LAST_FIRST 
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------
Smith      Ann                 1 Smith, Ann  
                               2             
Ang                            3 Ang         
           Murat               4 Murat
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE`

```
Select *,
       CASE WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL AND FirstName IS NOT NULL
            THEN LastName || ',' || FirstName AS Last_First_Name
       END lastname_firstname
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a CASE statement to conditionally add the comma:

```
CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL 
     THEN LastName || ','
     ELSE NULL
END
 || FirstName AS Last_First_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports [`NULLIF`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm).  If both first and last name are null, the result will just be `,` which can be filtered.

```
SELECT
    NULLIF(LastName ||','|| FirstName, ',') AS FullName
FROM table
```

Alternately, if you need to allow for when a single name is populated, you can use [`TRIM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) to remove leading/trailing commas.

```
SELECT
    TRIM(',', LastName ||','|| FirstName) AS FullName
FROM table
```

Comment: TRIM(x, y):   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

By analogy, you can do with anything, including names.

Consider the example address:

```
select 
    SUBSTR(
        (CASE WHEN city is null THEN '' ELSE  ', ' || city END) ||
        (CASE WHEN street is null THEN '' ELSE ', ' || street END) ||
        (CASE WHEN house is null THEN '' ELSE ', ' || house END) ||
        (CASE WHEN addition is null THEN '' ELSE ', ' || addition END)
    , 3) as address
from departments;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate any number of fields with delimiters using:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Col1 || ',' || Col2 || ',' || Col3, ',,*', ','), '^,|,$', '')
```

The inner REGEXP_REPLACE removes repeated delimiters occurring when you have interior NULL values.
The outer REGEXP_REPLACE removes the leading and trailing delimiters occurring if your list of values starts or ends with NULL.
If all values are NULL, returns NULL.

Comment: If you have a multi-character delimiter (comma-space), enclose it in parentheses in the inner REGEXP_REPLACE: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(Col1 || ', ' || Col2 || ', ' || Col3, '(, ){2,}', ', '), '^, |, $', '')`